# Do I need to worry about random nameless HEPA filters containing asbestos?

Tags: asbestos, air-quality

I bought a cheap "DIY" air purifier with HEPA filter. I think it was this one > https://smartairfilters.com/cn/en/product/hepa-filter/

Then I started reading the history of HEPA filters and found out that they were made with asbestos back in the WW2-Cold war era (just like the particulate layer in gas mask filters).

Do I need to worry about this potentially containing asbestos? Or are modern HEPA filters definitely not made with asbestos?

I also bought some other cheap chinese-made HEPA filters, so the question is not just about that specific one I linked, but more in general.

Comment: Just my opinion but if you purchased a cheap, nameless HEPA filter from China, you're not concerned about your health so "no", don't worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not be too concerned about a HEPA - or any new filter - containing asbestos. Asbestos has been so clearly outlawed for a long time in pretty much any consumer facing usage, **especially** anything that could result in airborne asbestos (which is the concern - solid/encapsulated is just not a problem) that I find it hard to believe even the Chinese would try to sneak it in, presumably to save a few $.

However, unless the filters are certified by some 3rd-party (preferably US or Europe based) company/organization, I would also not assume that cheap Chinese filters are actually **HEPA** quality. That is a significant step above ordinary filters. I would treat that "HEPA" label as "hopefully a step above the *regular* filters from the same company". If you truly need HEPA filtration, don't really on the cheap Chinese stuff.

The Chinese are perfectly capable of producing top-quality products (iPhone, Tesla, etc.) but they are well-known to cut corners and to mislabel items in many different ways when they can. So without a known reputable company or 3rd-party testing, treat these filters as "inexpensive and *possibly* HEPA" and don't rely on them if you need "clean room" quality or have very allergic people to protect, etc.

Comment: No one country has a monopoly on greedy business men/politicians who place profit above human safety. (*or everything else for that matter.*)  Murican corporations are perfectly capable of following consumer and environmental laws designed to make the world a safer place but Many, not all, choose to use manufacturers from places that do not have these protections in place, or are willing to ignore them, simply for the greed  and the desire  for a **larger** profit than they would otherwise get.

Comment: @AlaskaMan You are 100% correct. The difference, in my perception which of course is only one man's view, is that many countries, including the good ol' US of A, have laws for consumer protection, truth in advertising, etc. that are enforced to a degree that most (though certainly not all) companies make a good faith effort to follow the rules, whether due to innate moral sense or simply because they don't want to get fined/etc. On the other hand, if the items are designed, produced and exported from a country that has a lower sense of legal responsibility **and** they are imported into

Comment: the US of A (or similar countries) in a way that they can easily evade strict enforcement of laws, they will often do so. In addition to information from other random people on the internet (e.g., Harper), I have heard first-hand accounts from reputable people who have gone to China to supervise production of items destined for the US of A and been astounded at the lengths to which some people there will go in order to cheat the system.